# Mac10.11 install php memcached in Xammp

Tags: php, xampp

My development environment is Mac 10.11.1,XAMPP for OS X 5.6.12.
I want to install memcached for XAMMP refer to http://wiki.cerbweb.com/Setup:Development/XAMPP/Mac_OS_X#zlib :

```html
Memcache
- sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install memcache
- 'Yes' when prompted
- stop and start Apache from XAMPP Control Panel.app
- Confirm memcache extension in http://localhost/xampp/phpinfo.php
```

but when I run `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install memcache`
It like that:

```html
gaosongdeMacBook-Pro:bin gaosong$ sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install memcache
downloading memcache-2.2.7.tgz ...
Starting to download memcache-2.2.7.tgz (36,459 bytes)
..........done: 36,459 bytes
11 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
Enable memcache session handler support? [yes] : 
building in /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-roote06YHQ/memcache-2.2.7
running: /private/tmp/pear/install/memcache/configure --enable-memcache-session=yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable memcache support... yes, shared
checking whether to enable memcache session handler support... yes
checking for the location of ZLIB... no
checking for the location of zlib... configure: error: memcache support requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/memcache/configure --enable-memcache-session=yes' failed
```

But I have installed ZLIB by homebrew:

```
gaosongdeMacBook-Pro:~ gaosong$ brew install zlib
Warning: homebrew/dupes/zlib-1.2.8 already installed
```

I Use --with-zlib-dir= to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located like that :

```
sudo ./pecl install memcached --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/opt/zlib
```

or

```
sudo ./pecl install memcache --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local
```

but it get the same result :(

Could you help me to install the memcache successfully？
Thank you very much!